# Logging each JUnit test on different log file in multi-thread environment

Tags: java, multithreading, junit, sifting-appender

I would like to create a log for each JUnit Test I have run, each having its own file.

Actually, I have done that yesterday, with the help of Logback's [SiftingAppender](https://logback.qos.ch/manual/appenders.html#SiftingAppender).

```java
import java.lang.reflect.AnnotatedElement;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.DisplayName;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Order;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.AfterEachCallback;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.BeforeEachCallback;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtensionContext;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.slf4j.MDC;

public class CustomJUnitTestRule implements AfterEachCallback, BeforeEachCallback {

    @Override
    public void beforeEach(ExtensionContext extensionContext) throws Exception {
        Class<?> testClass = extensionContext.getTestClass().get();
        AnnotatedElement annotatedElement = extensionContext.getElement().get();
        Method method = extensionContext.getTestMethod().get();
        String methodName = method.getName();
        DisplayName displayName = testClass.getAnnotation(DisplayName.class);
        String topic = displayName.value();
        boolean annotationPresent = annotatedElement.isAnnotationPresent(Order.class);
        int order = -1;
        if (annotationPresent) {
            Order orderAnnotation = annotatedElement.getAnnotation(Order.class);
            order = orderAnnotation.value();
        }
        String fileName = String.format("%s-%02d-%s", topic, order, methodName);
        MDC.put("testId", fileName);
    }

    @Override
    public void afterEach(ExtensionContext extensionContext) throws Exception {
        MDC.remove("testId");
    }
}
```

with a sample logback.xml

```xml
<configuration>

  <appender name="SIFT" class="ch.qos.logback.classic.sift.SiftingAppender">
    <!-- in the absence of the class attribute, it is assumed that the
         desired discriminator type is
         ch.qos.logback.classic.sift.MDCBasedDiscriminator -->
    <discriminator>
      <key>testId</key>
      <defaultValue>unknown</defaultValue>
    </discriminator>
    <sift>
      <appender name="FILE-${userid}" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
        <file>${testId}.log</file>
        <append>false</append>
        <layout class="ch.qos.logback.classic.PatternLayout">
          <pattern>%d [%thread] %level %mdc %logger{35} - %msg%n</pattern>
        </layout>
      </appender>
    </sift>
  </appender>

  <root level="DEBUG">
    <appender-ref ref="SIFT" />
  </root>
</configuration>
```

and a simple test

```java
@TestInstance(TestInstance.Lifecycle.PER_CLASS)
@DisplayName("abc")
public class ABCTest {
    @Test
    @Order(1)
    public void xxxTest() {
        // ...
    }
}
```

It is working as intended at the first sight.

However **as it uses MDC to work in the background, which essentially is thread bounded**, which makes some of my unit test, which creates multiple thread, not working as intended.

> Can I create a logback's appender, which is not MDC bound, but globally, so that all logs in different threads (other than thread running jUnit test case), can be found in the log file as well?

Comment: Have you tried running without the method name in the file name? Like this - String fileName = String.format("%s-%02d-%s", topic, order);  ?

Comment: The problem lies on MDC, so it shouldn't be a problem of having method name or not.